# Finding the shortest distance between an ellipse and a point

Tags: geometry

I have an ellipse given by:

$$9x^2+16y^2=144$$
and I need to determine  the point on the ellipse that is closest to the line passing through the point $A=(5,2)$ and is perpendicular to the line $$l:  = 7 + x.$$

I try to set the ellipse equal to the tangent line first:

$$9x^2+16y^2-144=7 + x$$

But this cannot be solved.

Any ideas appreciated..

Comment: Are you familiar with constrained optimization/Lagrange multipliers? I can think of a simple strategy to solve your problem, but if you need a "purely geometrical" argument then I'm not sure I can help.

Comment: @CarlosSantiToledo What are you talking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the derivative: $18x+32yy'=0$.  We know that $y'=-1$, hence $9x=16y$.  Now substitute $y=\frac{9}{16}x$ in $9x^2+16y^2=144$ to get the solutions $\pm(16/5,9/5)$.

Comment: How did you get $18x+32yy'=0$? And how do we know that $y'=-1$? When I insert $y=\frac{9}{16}x$ in the equation, I get $9x^2+16\cdot \frac{81}{256}-144=0$, I get $x=\pm \sqrt(247)/4$ that gives $(\sqrt(247)/4, \frac{9}{16})$ and $(-\sqrt(247)/4, \frac{9}{16})$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Write a perpendicular to $y=x+7$ which passes through $A$

> It is $y=-x +7$

So you need to find a line parallel to $\ell$ which is tangent to ellipse.

So you have to solve an equation $$9x^2 +16(-x+n)^2 = 144$$ which has only one solution in $x$. This means that it discriminant is $0$. So you get an $n$ and then $x$ of a touching point $D$. Then calculate $d(D,\ell)$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to find a point which closest to a set, constrained optimization comes to mind.

As nonuser suggests, the perpendicular to $y = x + 7$ which passes through $A$ is given by:
$$
y = -x+7.
$$
Now, I'll try to phrase your problem from an "optimization point of view": you want to find a point $p_1 = [x_1,y_1]$ on the ellipse which is closest to a point $p_2 = [x_2,y_2]$ on the line. More formally, you can write your problem as:
$$
\min_{9x_1^2+16y_1^2 = 144\\y_2=-x_2+7}\left[(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2\right],
$$
where $(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2$ represents the distance between $p_1$ and $p_2$. Once you solve this problem (in four variables!), the point $p_1$ will be the point you're looking for.

(In this case, it is the point $p_1 = \left[\frac{16}{5},\frac{9}{5}\right]$.)

Answer (score 1):

Here,We can use concept ofmultivariable calculus.
First
given,$y-x=7$

Eqn of line perpendicular to this line is
$x+y=k$
since,$(5,2)$ is on the line ,we get $k=7$

Required equation of line:
$x+y=7$
Consider,
$F(x,y)=\frac{(x+y-7)^2}{2}$
subject to the constraint
$G(x,y)=0$ where $G(x,y)=9x^2+16y^2-144$

By langrange multiplier method

$\nabla F= c•\nabla G$

$(x+y-7,y+x-7)=(18cx,32cy)$
We get, $c=0$ or $18x=32y$
Now,$c=0$ gives distance 0 which is not possible.
Now,
$x=\frac{16y}{9}$

Now, put this value on eqn of ellipse
we get,
$9(\frac{(16y)^2}{81})+16y^2=144$

$256y^2+144y^2=9\times 144$

$400y^2=9\times 144$
then,
$y=+-\frac{9}{5}$
And
$x=+- \frac{16}{5}$

So the points are $(\frac{16}{5},\frac{9}{5}),(\frac{-16}{5},\frac{-9}{5})$
Now, Find value of $F$ at these points.
The point gives minimam value will be point with shortest distance

Answer (score 1):

The line passes through $A(5,2)$ and is perpendicular to $ y = 7 + x$, so its equation is $ y = 7 - x$

From the equation of the ellipse,

$ 9 x^2 + 16 y^2 = 144 $

So

$ \dfrac{x^2}{16} + \dfrac{y^2}{9} = 1 $

Hence the parametric equation of the ellipse is

$ P = (x, y) = (4 \cos t , 3 \sin t )$

The distance between $P$ and the line is

$ d = \dfrac{ | 4 \cos t + 3 \sin t - 7 |}{\sqrt{2}} $

Now $4 \cos t + 3 \sin t = 5 \cos(t - t_0) $ where $ t_0 = \tan^{-1}(\dfrac{3}{4}) $

Thus $ 4 \cos t + 3 \sin t - 7 = 5 \cos (t - t_0) - 7 $ is always negative and therefore, its absolute value is minimum when $5 \cos(t - t_0)$ is maximum, i.e. when $t = t_0 $.  In this case we have

$ d_{Min} = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2} $

And the point that gives that minimum distance is

$ P = (4 \cos t_0, 3 \sin t_0 ) $

Comment: @Luthier415Hz  I divided the equation by $144$.